# Is there a quick Riemann surface calculator?

Tags: reference-request, riemann-surfaces

Sometimes I just want to know what a complex function looks like, and for some reason Wolfram never processes my Riemann surface command. Is there some site what will just let me enter in an equation and plot its Riemann surface?

Comment: Nothing you can't get from google images of Riemann surfaces. I can't provide an specific example of an online calculator. Please reread the question, that "example" is literally what I am trying to find and explicitly what the question asks about.

Comment: You yourself can just google images of Riemann surfaces, there is nothing I can provide here that you can't provide for yourself in a fraction of the time.